# React-Native FilesyStem Download

Tags: react-native, asynchronous, download, filesystems, expo

I am writing an app in react-native which must allow users to download documents to their devices and have a few questions.

Firstly, the code. I want to make sure I have this set up properly. I'm using the expo environment. these are the relevant parts:

```
import * as FileSystem from 'expo-file-system';

const Listitem = ({ item, setDownloading }) => {

  const {
    doc, // this is a filepath to the document on a webserver 
    doc_title,
    title } = item;

  const downloadFile = async () => {
    setDownloading(true);
    console.log('fired');

    FileSystem.downloadAsync(
      doc,
      FileSystem.documentDirectory + doc_title
    )
      .then(({ uri }) => {
        setDownloading(false);
        console.log('Finished downloading to ', uri); // results are show below
      })
      .catch(error => {
        setDownloading(false);
        console.error(error);
      });
  }

  return !title ? null : (
    <View>
      {doc != '' &&
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={ downloadFile }>
            <Text>download file</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      }
    </View>
}
```

When triggered, the log looks like this from Android Studio Simulator:

```
Finished downloading to  file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/files/ExperienceData/%2540anonymous%252Fapp-name-34c241e6-2364-40cb-bd45-b8e8fcc0d87e/document_name.pptx
```

And like this on my iPhone in the expo environment:

```
Finished downloading to  file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/5F58DB37-FF66-4CAF-8520-A0D82C7B3EF3/Documents/ExponentExperienceData/%2540anonymous%252Fapp-name-34c241e6-2364-40cb-bd45-b8e8fcc0d87e/document_name.pptx
```

So my questions are:

1. Am I doing this right?
2. Where can I find the downloaded files? Because I've looked all over for them (both in the emulator and on my phone) and am not finding anything.

Thanks so much for any help!